# Adding data from list to CSV using OpenCSV...but failed to map the data to individual rows

Tags: opencsv

Here iam using OpenCSV library to insert data in list "li" to CSV file...my code is like this...

```
/* To parse CSV file Iam using OPENCSV 2.4 library*/ 

    String file = "src/main/resources/csv/outbox.txt";

            CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            writer.writeAll(li);
            writer.close();
```

and after executing the application the data in CSV is like this....

Date           Time Code
11-06-2014
10:18:09
12
12-02-2014
11:02:00
22
02-03-2014
03:00:00
3
23-02-2014
04:00:00
123
02-01-2014
04:00:12
43

but i need to print my data in its individual column not in first column....

can u please suggest how to map data into particular rows....